# Create a MySQL insert query using a nested dictionary and custom parameters

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary "**sample_dict** and a few **Parameters**  in Python :

```
import pandas as pd

#Parameters
Condition_Name='ID_0.5_365D'
Insert_Date='2021-05-19 00:00:00'

sample_dict=\
{pd.Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'): {'navi.o_efx': 180.0,
  'navi.o_qrvo.o': 180.0,
  'navi.o_stm.n': 180.0,
  'qrvo.o_efx': 1.0,
  'qrvo.o_stm.n': 1.0},
 pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'): {'navi.o_efx': 179.0,
  'navi.o_stm.n': 179.0}}
```

which, for a given date, has varying keys and values.

The structure of the MySQL table "**sample_table**" intended for insertion is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table (
  Date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  Pair_Name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  Condition_Name varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  Condition_Value double(16, 4) DEFAULT NULL,
  Insert_Date datetime DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 159,
CHARACTER SET latin1,
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

How can a MySQL insert query be created by using for loops in Python by merging the "**sample_dict**" and "**Parameters**"? For example, the output query should be created in the below shown format:

```
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00','navi.o_efx','ID_0.5_365D',180,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'navi.o_qrvo.o','ID_0.5_365D',180,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00',  'navi.o_stm.n','ID_0.5_365D',180,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00',  'qrvo.o_efx','ID_0.5_365D',1,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00',  'qrvo.o_stm.n','ID_0.5_365D',1,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2014-12-31 00:00:00','navi.o_efx','ID_0.5_365D',179,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name,Condition_Value,Insert_Date) VALUES ('2014-12-31 00:00:00','navi.o_stm.n','ID_0.5_365D',179,'2021-05-19 00:00:00');
```

The final inserts in the "**sample_table**" would look like this:

[image]

Comment: *The final inserts in the "sample_table" would like this:* 1) Post as text, not as a picture (with proper formatting); 2) Show the output which matches shown source data strictly (not "like this").

Comment: @Akina: I have posted the inserts and their EXACT corresponding output. Please take the time to  go thought it, before criticizing ! :)

Comment: Oops... sorry. I was confused by the 12 hour value (and the non-standard datetime format for MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

If you want simple string construction, this should do:

```py
prefix = 'INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('
for timestamp, samples in sample_dict.items():
    for pair_name, condition_value in samples.items():
        print(f"{prefix}'{timestamp}', '{pair_name}', '{Condition_Name}', {condition_value}, '{Insert_Date}');")
```

output:

```sql
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'navi.o_efx', 'ID_0.5_365D', 180.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'navi.o_qrvo.o', 'ID_0.5_365D', 180.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'navi.o_stm.n', 'ID_0.5_365D', 180.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'qrvo.o_efx', 'ID_0.5_365D', 1.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2015-01-02 00:00:00', 'qrvo.o_stm.n', 'ID_0.5_365D', 1.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2014-12-31 00:00:00', 'navi.o_efx', 'ID_0.5_365D', 179.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
INSERT INTO sample_table(Date, Pair_Name, Condition_Name, Condition_Value, Insert_Date) VALUES ('2014-12-31 00:00:00', 'navi.o_stm.n', 'ID_0.5_365D', 179.0, '2021-05-19 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can even directly insert into mysql:

```
import pandas as pd

import mysql.connector

from sqlalchemy import create_engine

result_dict, result_list = {}, []

#collect input

Condition_Name='ID_0.5_365D'

Insert_Date='2021-05-19 00:00:00'

sample_dict=\
{pd.Timestamp('2015-01-02 00:00:00'): {'navi.o_efx': 180.0,
  'navi.o_qrvo.o': 180.0,
  'navi.o_stm.n': 180.0,
  'qrvo.o_efx': 1.0,
  'qrvo.o_stm.n': 1.0},
 pd.Timestamp('2014-12-31 00:00:00'): {'navi.o_efx': 179.0,
  'navi.o_stm.n': 179.0}}

#populate result_dict
for key,value in sample_dict.items():
    for item_key, item_value in value.items():
        result_dict['condition_name']=Condition_Name
        result_dict['insert_date']=Insert_Date
        result_dict['date']=key
        result_dict['pair_name']=item_key
        result_dict['pair_value']=item_value
        result_list.append(result_dict.copy())

index_list = range(1, len(result_list)+1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(result_list, columns = ['index', 'condition_name', 'insert_date', 'date', 'pair_name', 'pair_value'], index= index_list)

#dump into mysql
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]/[schema]', echo = False)
df1.to_sql(name = 'my_table', con = engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The value in result_dict gets overwritten after every loop. Could you correct the solution

Comment: @PrateekDaniels yep, my bad. changes done
cheers!

Comment: Thanks for making the change, but it's still wrong. The list "result_list" produces duplicate entries of date:'2014-12-31 00:00:00'

Comment: The result_list should have seven unique entries

Comment: I figured out the error, the corrected line of code should be :
 result_list.append(result_dict.copy())